# Почему при формировании файлов xml в начале добавляются пустые строки

Tags: xml, php, администрирование

Добрый вечер. Никак не могу решить проблему. При формировании файлов `xml`, в начале добавляются пустые строки. Из-за них вылетает ошибка

> This page contains the following errors:
> error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
> Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Движок `Opencart 1.5.4.1`. Очень прошу о помощи.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<!DOCTYPE yml_catalog SYSTEM "shops.dtd">
<yml_catalog date="2013-02-19 00:25">
<shop>
<name></name>
<company></company>
<url></url>
<phone></phone>
<platform>ocStore</platform>
<version>1.5.4.1</version>
<currencies>
<currency id="USD" rate="1" />
</currencies>
<categories>  </categories>
<offers>  </offers>
</shop></yml_catalog>
```

Р”Р° С„РѕСЂРјРёСЂСѓРµС‚СЃСЏ РјРѕРґСѓР»РµРј. РћРґРёРЅ РјРѕРґСѓР»СЊ РґР»СЏ СЃРѕР·РґР°РЅРёСЏ sitemap, РІС‚РѕСЂРѕР№ РґР»СЏ СЃРѕР·РґР°РЅРёСЏ yml РєС‚Р°Р»РѕРіР°.

Comment: код покажите, как генерируете ?

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: http://fishing-trade.com/index.php?route=feed/yandex_market

Comment: Кодировку файла скрипта измените на UTF-8 БЕЗ BOM

Comment: Да изменял кодировку, не помогло (

Comment: Очищайте буфер вывода перед формированием xml.

Comment: А можно поподробнее? Я не знаю что за буфер

Comment: Декларация доктайпа должна идти первой. О чем красноречиво говорит ошибка.

    <!DOCTYPE yml_catalog SYSTEM "shops.dtd">

поставьте в начало.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, объявление версии xml всегда идет первым. Ошибка как раз и говорит о том, что версия объявлена не на первой строке.

А вообще забавно, всегда xml генерирую средствами `DOMDocument` (http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php), и никаких проблем. Зато как только народ пытается набрать xml текстом - сразу получаем нечто, что невозможно сопровождать и править, да еще и с кучей ошибок.

Comment: @Равнодушный, да вы правы. спать пора уже давно просто )

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, в морге отоспимся. Код сам себя не обыдлит... )